# insert real time json data into a mysql table

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, stomp

Openned a websocket tunnel and im able to see the json data on console.log and now i want to save that data stream locally, basically in a mysql database. I used Ajax and php to code the application.

Javascript Code:

```
    stomp.connect(headers, function(cb) {
        //Subscribe to a 3rd party 
        var topic = stomp.subscribe('/destination', function(e) {

            var mes = e;
            var body = JSON.parse(e.body);

            //Insert Data to mySQL
            function jsRecordInsertWrite(){

                var jsObject = {
                    "Time": document.body.timestamp.value,
                    "SourceId": document.body.sourceId.value,
                    "TrackingId": document.body.trackingId.value
                };

                // ... the AJAX request is successful
                var updatePage = function (response) {
                    alert("insert record successful");
                };
                // ... the AJAX request fail
                var printError = function (req, status, err) {
                    alert("insert record failed");
                };

                // Create an object to describe the AJAX request
                $.ajax({
                    url        : 'send.php',
                    dataType   : 'json',
                    contentType: 'application/json', 
                    data       : jsObject,
                    type       : 'POST',
                    success: updatePage,
                    error: printError
                });
            }


        }, headers);
    });
```

PHP Script:

```
<?php

//Creating a connection
$link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '','test');\

//read the json file contents
$id =  $_GET['id'];
$timestamp =  $_POST['Time'];
$sourceId =  $_POST['SourceId'];
$trackingId =  $_POST['TrackingId'];

//insert into mysql table
$sql = "INSERT INTO tbl_Data(id, Time, SourceId, TrackingId)   
VALUES(NULL,'$timestamp', '$sourceId', $trackingId')";

if(!mysql_query($sql)) {
    die('Error : ' . mysql_error());
}

//database connection close
mysql_close($link);

?>
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: what's the problem?

Comment: Im failing to insert that data in a database

Comment: 1/ Your URL is `send.php` and you write `$id =  $_GET['id'];` : your id is empty. 2/ In your $sql,  why you want to insert an id with NULL value? In your database id should be unique so try auto-incrementation and insert your value without inserting id, it will be created when insert.3/ `mysql_XX` is depreciated, you should use `mysqli` or `PDO` 4/ You should make prepare statement to avoid SQL injection

Comment: Please make use of prepared statements seeing as though you are using `mysqli_*`. Secondly, the id of the row should generally be AI (auto increment).